# Complex Parsec Parsers

Tags: haskell, parsec

I don't quite know how else to ask. I think I need general guidance here. I've got something like this:

```
expr = buildExpressionParser table term
    <?> "expression"

term = choice [
    (float >>= return . EDouble)
    , try (natural >>= return . EInteger)
    , try (stringLiteral >>= return . EString)
    , try (reserved "true" >> return (EBool True))
    , try (reserved "false" >> return (EBool False))
    , try assign
    , try ifelse
    , try lambda
    , try array
    , try eseq
    , parens expr
    ]
    <?> "simple expression"
```

When I test that parser, though, I mostly get problems... like when I try to parse

```
 (a,b) -> "b"
```

it is accepted by the `lambda` parser, but the `expr` parser hates it. And sometimes it even hangs up completely in eternal rules.

I've read through [Write Yourself a Scheme](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours), but it only parses the homogeneous source of Scheme.

Maybe I am generally thinking in the wrong direction.

**EDIT**: Here the internal parsers:

```
assign = do
    i <- identifier
    reservedOp "="
    e <- expr
    return $ EAssign i e

ifelse = do
    reserved "if"
    e <- expr
    reserved "then"
    a <- expr
    reserved "else"
    b <- expr
    return $ EIfElse e a b

lambda = do
    ls <- parens $ commaSep identifier
    reservedOp "->"
    e <- expr
    return $ ELambda ls e

array = (squares $ commaSep expr) >>= return . EArray

eseq = do
    a <- expr
    semi <|> (newline >>= (\x -> return [x]))
    b <- expr
    return $ ESequence a b

table = [
        [binary "*" EMult AssocLeft, binary "/" EDiv AssocLeft, binary "%" EMod AssocLeft ],
        [binary "+" EPlus AssocLeft, binary "-" EMinus   AssocLeft ],
        [binary "~" EConcat AssocLeft],
        [prefixF "not" ENot],
        [binaryF "and" EAnd AssocLeft, binaryF "or" EAnd AssocLeft]
    ]
```

And by "hates it" I meant that it tells me it expects an integer or a floating point.

Comment: We need the internals of the inside statements, because you probably have a grammar conflict. Also, what do you mean by "hates it"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be left recursion, which will cause the parser to hang if the `choice` in `term` ever gets to `eseq`:

`expr` -> `term` -> `eseq` -> `expr`

The `term` `(a,b)` will not parse as a `lambda`, or an `array`, so it will fall into the `eseq` loop.

I don't see why `(a,b) -> "b"` doesn't parse as an `expr`, since the `choice` in term should hit upon the `lambda`, which you say works, before reaching the `eseq`.  What is the position reported in the parse error?

Comment: I looked for that for 30 minutes and could not see it.  Well done. +1

Comment: Thanks for the input. I took the `eseq`, `array` and `lambda` to a different combinator, more ebnf like now. And it seems to work now.

Answer (score 6):

What Edward in the comments and I are both trying to do is mentally run your parser, and that is a little difficult without more of the parser to go on. I'm going to make some guesses here, and maybe they will help you refine your question.

**Guess 1)**:  You have tried `GHCI> parse expr "(input)" "(a,b) -> \"b\"` and it has returned `Left …`. It would be helpful to know what the error was.

**Guess 2)**: You have also tried `GHCI> parse lambda "(input)" "(a,b) -> \"b\"` and it returned `Right …`.  based on this Edward an I have both deduced that somewhere in either your `term` parser or perhaps in the generated `expr` parser there is a conflict  That is some piece of the parser is succeeding in matching the beginning of the string and returning a value, but what remains is no longer valid.  It would be helpful if you would try `GHCI> parse term "(input)" "(a,b) -> \"b\"` as this would let us know whether the problem was in `term` or `expr`.

**Guess 3)**: The string `"(a,b)"` is by itself a valid expression in the grammar as you have programmed it. (Though perhaps not as you *intended* to program it ;-).  Try sending that through the expr parser and see what happens.

**Guess 4)**: Your grammar is left recursive.  This is what causes it to get stuck and loop forever.  Parsec is a LL(k) parser.  If you are used to Yacc and family which are LR(1) or LR(k) parsers, the rules for recursion are exactly reversed.  If you didn't understand this last sentence thats OK, but let us know.

**Guess 5)**: The code in the expression builder looks like it came from the function's documentation.  I think you may have found the `term` expression somewhere as well.  If that is the case you you point to where it came from. if not could you explain in a few sentences how you think `term` ought to work.

---

**General Advice**:  The large number of `try` statements are eventually (a.k.a. now) going to cause you grief.  They are useful in some cases but also a little naughty.  If the next character can determine what choice should succeed there is no need for them.  If you are just trying to get something running lots of backtracking will reduce the number of intermediate forms, but it also hides pathological cases and makes errors more obscure.

Comment: Nice psychic debugging. I'd place my money on at least one of those guesses.

Comment: The term `"(a,b)"` causes a loop. And the `term` is supposed to, well, evaluate everything I want to allow as a term in an expression. I actually want something like `a = z + (if true then 1 else 2)`